# Segmentation fault when using `getopt_long` with an unrecognized long option

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I use the `getopt_long` function in my new program.
It runs good when passing a valid long option. But if I try to invoke the program with an invalid option, i.e. `--unknown`, the execution is halted saying that a segmentation fault occurred. Full command is `program version --unknown`.

Where do I need to change code to make my program work again?
(Note: it is fine when passing a invalid **short** option)

This is for a command-line program. It needs to receive sub-commands as its first argument and options specific to each sub-command. I wanted to add support for long options because working with short ones is really difficult.

```
char* subcommand = /* ... */;
int option_char = 0;
int exit_code = 0;

/* ... */
// Note: argv should be an array of strings containing the command-line arguments
int pm_parse_arguments(int argc, char** argv) {
    opterr = 0;
    if(strcmp(subcommand, "version") == 0) {
        return pm_parse_version_arguments(argc, argv);
    } else {
        // No recognized subcommand
        pm_global_unrecognized_subcommand(subcommand);
    }
    return exit_code;
}

int pm_parse_version_arguments(int argc, char** argv) {
    // List of long options
    struct option long_options[] = {
        {"help",        no_argument, 0, 'h'},
        {"major",       no_argument, 0, 'm'},
        {"minor",       no_argument, 0, 0},
        {"revision",    no_argument, 0, 'r'},
    };

    // Index of option
    int option_index = 0;

    while((option_char = getopt_long(argc, argv, ":hmr", long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        switch(option_char) {
            /* ... */
        }
    return exit_code;
}
```

It should print `Unrecognized option: --unknown` when passing the long option `--unknown` like for the short ones. Instead, a segmentation error is returned.

Here is the [full output log of Valgrind](https://gist.github.com/mlaunois/c727be171198967e0091e64f541573e3) in verbose mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopt_long` requires the array of long options to be terminated with a zeroed options struct (similar to how strings are null-terminated). Otherwise, it wouldn't know how many there were.

Comment: I added zeroed options struct to the long options array and it solved my problem about segmentation fault, thanks! Note that **a NULL struct may be used** instead of the zeroed options struct.

Comment: That's not a "null struct"; there's no such thing in C. `NULL` is defined to `0`, which zero-initializes.